# Пересёк или пересѐк, пересёкший или пересѐкший — как правильно?

Tags: орфография, словообразование, глаголы, причастия, е-или-ё

*От Ангары и всей Сибири,

Чей на земле в расцвете век,—

От этой дали, этой шири,

Что я недаром **пересѐк**.*
[**А. Т. Твардовский. За далью — даль**](http://moremhod.info/index.php/library-menu/25-poeziya/125-3?showall=&start=2)

Я всегда считала, что *он пересёк* — верно, а поэт меня озадачил (никогда раньше не задумывалась — не обращала внимания).

[**Викисловарь**](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C) даёт формы "пересёк" и "пересёкший". А как правильно:
*перес**ё**к или перес**ѐ**к, перес**ё**кший или перес**ѐ**кший* (границу, черту, предел...)?

Comment: Беда какая-то! Не смог поставить нормальные ударения. :(

Answer (score 5):

> *От Ангары и всей Сибири,*
>
> *Чей на земле в расцвете **вѐк**,—*
>
> *От этой дали, этой шири,*
>
> *Что я недаром **пересѐк**.*
>
> ***А.Т.Твардовский, "За далью — даль"***

Твардовский не отступил от норм литературного языка, употребив форму ***пересѐк***. Этот вариант являлся **единственно правильным** во время написания им книги "За далью — даль".

См. [***"Русское литературное ударение и произношение. Опыт словаря-справочника"*** под ред. Р.И. Аванесова и С.И. Ожегова; М., 1955]:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В наше время более предпочтительна форма ***пересёк.***

***Пересѐк*** же большая часть словаристов относит к устаревшей лексике.

А вот из форм причастий прошедшего времени более нормативной в наши дни считается форма с "е": ***пересѐкший.***

Вот что рекомендует, к примеру, ***"Большой универсальный словарь русского языка"*** под ред. Морковкина (М., 2016):

> *прич. действ. прош*. **пересѐкший** *и хуже* **пересёкший**.

Примерно так же говорится о форме причастий и в ***"Кратком словаре трудностей русского языка"*** у Еськовой:

> *прич. действ. прош*. **пересѐкший** *и допустимо* **пересёкший**.

Comment: "Твардовский не отступил от норм литературного языка, употребив форму пересѐк". Что Вы! — у меня и мысли не возникало по поводу отступлений. Просто хотелось понять, почему поэт использовал именно ЭТОТ вариант  формы глагола.

Comment: _Римма Михайлова: Что Вы! — у меня и мысли не возникало по поводу отступлений._ === Ну, а Вас-то, может, и не возникало. А вот у Sibylla... См. её: _форма "пересек" только допускалась и скорее была использована для рифмы._

Answer (score 3):

**У Резниченко (2010 год)** приводятся две формы: пересёк и пересек;  пересёкший и пересекший.

**А вот у Аванесова (1983 год) такие варианты:** пересёк и доп. устар. пересек;  пересекший и доп. пересёкший.

Годы создания поэмы  - 1950-1960, тогда, если верить Аванесову, форма "пересек" только допускалась и скорее была использована для рифмы.

Answer (score 2):

Пересечь(ся), -секу(сь), -сечёт(ся), -секут(ся); прош. -с**ё**к(ся) и -сек(ся), -секла(сь)

**Академический орфографический словарь, Лопатин.**

Answer (score 1):

Сек (сечь) - это морф с историческим ятем, такие корни приобрели ё только в единичных случаях и, как правило, много позже всех остальных. Поэтому в словари за специальным подтверждением можно и не лазить. 
Правильно будет сказать, что пересёк, пересёкший -  современная норма, "пересек" и "пересекший" - устаревший и поэтический вариант.

Твардовский, безусловно, застал ещё период активной формы "пересек", причем такие формы с историческим Е/Ятем на месте современных Ё в поэзии всегда являлись атрибутом высокого стиля.

Есть один популярный и сочный пример такого стиля, он не совсем, правда, в тему, ибо там другая причина чередования Е/Ё, но все-таки.

> Исчез властитель осужденный,
>   Могучий баловень побед,
>   И для изгнанника вселенной
>   Уже потомство настает.

(Пушкин, "Наполеон")

Тут можно спорить, как эти слова звучали во времена Пушкина в быту, но в стихах высокого стиля молодой Пушкин явно под Державина и Ломоносова "работал".

Думаю, что Твардовский с его чувством языка, будь даже у него выбор, тоже поступил бы так же. Идею "сказал ради рифмы" я отвергаю в корне. Не тот уровень поэта, чтобы в угоду рифме или просто "ради в строку влезло" выбирать "незвучащий" вариант слова.

> Я всегда считала, что "он пересёк" — верно, а поэт меня озадачил
>   (никогда раньше не задумывалась — не обращала внимания).

"Всегда" ничего не бывает. Не очень даже понятно, когда вообще произошло это фонетическое явление (появление позиционного О - орфографическое Ё - после смягченных согласных) - ну не раньше же 15-го столетия?! А уж самой букве Ё три века от роду.

Однако в сознании многих именно эта буква воспринимается чуть ли не как самый незыблемый элемент русской графики (а заодно и фонетики), олицетворяющий саму русскую письменность со времен братьев Солунских.

Ваш пример - один из тех, которые доказывают, что это далеко не так. С этой буквой (и сугубо позиционным аллофоном, ей соответствующим) надо бы поаккуратнее.

Comment: Я подзапуталась с "ятями". Вы имеете в виду слова, писавшиеся через "ять", но произносившиеся со звуком "ё"? Они ведь были точно известны — как исключения: "звёзды", "гнёзда"...

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова По поводу Гнёзд и звёзд. Формулировка у вас неправильная. Написание даже в этих случаях соответствовало произношению. Но есть ряд слов, где исторический корневой ять перешел в Ё. Это не те слова, которые вы привели в качестве "исключений", это другой случай, орфографический казус, в чем-то обратный. Там ять стали писался не в силу исторической морфолгии, а **вопреки** ей. "Звезда" и "Гнездо" - это исторические корни  с естем, не с ятем. Долго всё это объяснять, ну сравните зотя бы с украинским, там рефлексом ятя является i, не е. А в зтих словах - е, как и в русском.

Comment: Ять там, видимо, вторичен (под влиянием польского, что ли?)... Я же имел в виду другие случаи, их несколько больше, но это именно исключения, а не казусы. Вики, например, вслед за некоторім авторами, просто не различает эти случаи. Про Сечь она говорит вот что: ***Из глаголов на -ечь через ѣ пишется только сѣчь с производными; у всех прочих обычное «е» (беречь, жечь, лечь, печь, (из-)речь, стеречь, течь и т. п.).*** Это закономерность некая, которую "сечь" нарушает, но не объяснение. А вот запоминалка из на те случаи, о которых упоминал я.

Comment: ***Ѣ не пишется при произношении «ё» и при чередованиях с «ё»: мёдъ, медовый, медоваръ; тёлка, телецъ, телёнокъ; пень, опёнокъ… Исключения из этого правила (то есть слова с ѣ на месте нынешней «ё»): вдѣжка, вѣшка, гнѣзда, запечатлѣнъ, засѣкъ, звѣзды, зѣвывалъ (и позѣвывалъ), издѣвка, медвѣдка (сейчас говорят без «ё»: медве́дка), надѣванъ, надѣвывалъ, обрѣлъ, смѣтка, сѣдла, подгнѣта, цвѣлъ и производные.*** Почему сюда попали звезды и гнёзды, но не "сечь", я не знаю. Может, именно потому, что "правило" достаточно древнее, когда Е/ятя в "пересек" еще не перешло в Ё.

Comment: Хотя там однокоренное "засёк" присутвует, может сочли достаточным.

Comment: Да, энное время назад с Вашей помощью пыталась разобраться с ятями. И совсем забыла про полезность. Спасибо (пусть и задним числом).